# Python difference between timezones

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-3.2

I have to create a code that can tell me the current time in any city (as a variable) and print the utc offset between that time and utc. I already have the following code which gives the current time and the offset from a timezone, but this timezone is not always utc. Note: the city names are stored in a text file and the user should be able to add and remove any city. I am using tkinter for the gui.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

def tz():
    utc = pytz.utc
    amsterdam = timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
    loc_dt = utc.localize(datetime.today())
    tz = loc_dt.astimezone(amsterdam)
    print(tz.strftime(fmt))
```

The file contents are as follows:

```
Amsterdam
Brasilia
Los Angeles
Abu Dhabi
Tokyo
Singapore
```

Can someone please help me with an easy code to do this? Thank you in advance

Comment: You say the city names are stored in a text file. Does this file also contain the UTC offset for each city, or are you expected to work that out yourself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12692910/4007642

Comment: We are expected to work it out for ourselves, the file only contains the names of the cities

Comment: Can you show us an excerpt of the text file you have with the city names?

Comment: What makes you think that arbitrary city names are unique on a global scale?  They are not.  Ex: Paris, France vs Paris, Texas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using pytz already, so I'd go for:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone, all_timezones

def to_timezone(dt, tz):
  assert dt.tzinfo is not None
  assert tz in all_timezones
  return dt.astimezone(timezone(tz))

print to_timezone(datetime.now(timezone('UTC')), 'Europe/Amsterdam')
```

I set it to UTC by default but the point is:

- have a non naive datetime
- convert it

Comment: I think I can work with this, thank you, but just one more thing, it still prints `CEST+0200`, will it always be CEST or is there a way too change it to UTC?

Comment: depends on what you want, if you use this to_timezone function, you will have it in the timezone you're asking, you can use it again to have it in utc this way: to_timezone(mycestdt, timezone('UTC'))